# Calc a 15-digit number into a BIGINT column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am using Linux and MySQL 5.6

I want to store a 15-digit NUMBER into a BIGINT column in MySQL.

The number is calculated as :

```
10000 * ( date +"%s" )  +   ` date +"%N" | cut -c1-5 `
```

where %s is the 10-digit epoch time
and %N is the nanosecond

How can I calculate this NUMBER in MySQL 5.6 SQL statement ?

```
Select 10000 * UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

can do the first part.

How to do the second part

Comment: do you want to get epoch time from date time and store it to BIG INT Column?

Comment: `Unix_timestamp()  * 1000000000` gives you nano seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00. From [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html): **If called with no argument, returns a Unix timestamp (seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC) as an unsigned integer. If UNIX_TIMESTAMP() is called with a date argument, it returns the value of the argument as seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC. date may be a DATE string, a DATETIME string, a TIMESTAMP, or a number in the format YYMMDD or YYYYMMDD.**

Comment: Unix_timestamp() return seconds (not nano seconds) since 1970-01-01 00:00:00.   In MySQL, [ Select Unix_timestamp() * 1000000000 ] will get a number with all ZEROS at the end, not with nanoseconds

Comment: Actually, what I want to do is to get the first 15 digits out of [ date +"%s%N" ].  Then, a prefix (e.g. 1997) will be added to make it a 19-digit number and then store it into a BIGINT column

Answer (score 0):

There is a a method like "cut" in MySQL.

```
SUBSTRING(str, pos, len)
```

But this + the string concatenation turns any number into a string. In another call this can be turned into BIGINT I guess like this:

```
CAST(your_number AS BIGINT);
```

A downside of this is, the casts and calls are rather expensive and your "nanosecond" thing is getting obsolete anyways.

It would be better(*) to use a bigint / unsigned auto increment ID and add an extra column with UNIQUEID or random stuff.

*) *I don't know your use-case.*